# Azure DB Connection Issues from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, console-application, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine

I have a particular C# windows console app that runs roughly every five minutes from a Azure VM. Each run starts by connecting to my Azure SQL Server DB. Roughly every 5ish attempts (essentially every 25 mins). One of these attempts to reach the DB will fail with the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

This seems like a much to frequent re-occurring event. On the same VM, I also have a web service setup to connect to the same Azure SQL Server DB, which I use as a mobile backend for one of my iOS apps. Literally every other call to the web service, where the DB is involved, I will receive a same/similar error.

Why exactly would this be happening? Is there a better coding method or connecting method that I should be using??

**Update:** I switched to using [DataContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) which seemed to solve most of these issues. It still happens, just not as frequently. I wonder, would this have anything to do with issues when simultaneous connections are made from completely separate programs? Perhaps my SQL Server can't handle multiple connections properly?

Comment: Have you checked the event log on the VM for any errors or related logs that might be connected to the db unavailability?

Comment: Are you closing connections every time or are you keeping them open?

Comment: @pootzko Yes, the connections are being closed.

Comment: @Gerneio Is it SQL database or SQL Server running on your VM? I'm a little bit lost here since it seems you are connecting via named pipes.

Comment: Nothing SQL wise is running on the VM. The SQL Server and DB are running directly off of Azure. The VM is simply connect to the Azure SQL Server to retrieve some data for a script.